# Want to upload and save image through pure javascript without any third party library

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, regex

I am learning JavaScript and was trying to upload and store an image without using libraries. The image is stored successfully but the file is giving an error when I open it. Here is the client side code:

```
 function myfunction() {

            let photo = document.getElementById("image-file").files[0];
            let formData = new FormData();
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let blob;
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(photo);
            reader.onload = (e) => blob = new Blob([e.target.result]);
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                formData.append(photo.name, blob);
                fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload', { method: "POST", body: formData });
            }
        }
```

Here is the server side code:

```
function store_file(req, res) {
    
    let body = Buffer.from([]);
    req.on('data', (data) => {
        body = Buffer.concat([body, data]);
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        if (req.headers.hasOwnProperty('content-type') && req.headers['content-type'].indexOf('boundary=') > -1) {
            let parts = req.headers['content-type'].split('boundary=');
            let boundary = parts[1];
            if (body.length > 0) {
                // actualBody = actualBody.replace(/.+?\r\n/gm, '');
                fs.writeFile('test.jpeg', body, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('The file has been saved!');
                });
            }
            index_file(req, res);
        }
        else {
            //bad request
            res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            res.write("missing boundary in content-type");
            res.end();
        }
    });
}
```

i have tried to hexdump the original image and the store image but there are multiple differences in the hexdump of these images. Can anyone tell, why these differences are occurring and how to resolve them?

Comment: Loose all the `reader` code and simply `formData.append("image-file", photo);`

Comment: Thanks @bloodyKnuckles I have completed the code and the image is saved properly. I tried something else